# Is there a good/best practice for temporary changes in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Sometimes, I need temporary changes in a playbook. Like adding a firewall rule, do things, and remove the firewall rule again. Or adding a local package repository mirror, install packages from it, and remove it again.

Currently, I implement at least two tasks for each temporary change. One that adds something and one that removes it again after everything else finished. I also tend to use `changed_when: false` for those tasks, because they are not really there to define a desired state, but they are a tool or a workaround *to be able* to configure a desired state during a development phase.

It works this way, but does not feel very *ansible-ish*. So I am wondering, are there better practices to implement temporary changes in Ansible?

Comment: you can use [playbook tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html)